# How to determine colors in an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, colors

I have a program which takes a picture and it then determines the RGB values of a portion of pixels I am interested in. I take the average RGB of the regions and put those in an array. What I want to do is go through that array and say based on its RGB value that it is for example "Orange". I want to do this without constraining the RGB values like this. `if(r > 10 && g < 200 && b < 200) color is green.` The reason being that lighting in the image can change a lot. So it could fall out of range if I give it hard constraints. I am trying to think of how to do it so that it is dynamic and works with no matter the lighting in the photo.

This isn't really a code problem I am trying to think of ways of how I can solve this. Can't seem to think of other ways of doing it without using constraints as I mentioned above which is why I came here.

Here is an example of a color array. (There are 24 colors in it)

```
Color Array: [java.awt.Color[r=6,g=115,b=77], java.awt.Color[r=6,g=115,b=77], java.awt.Color[r=6,g=115,b=77], java.awt.Color[r=6,g=115,b=77], java.awt.Color[r=248,g=184,b=40], java.awt.Color[r=241,g=26,b=27], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=38,b=183], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=38,b=183], java.awt.Color[r=178,g=168,b=204], java.awt.Color[r=198,g=148,b=22], java.awt.Color[r=185,g=140,b=6], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=38,b=183], java.awt.Color[r=241,g=26,b=27], java.awt.Color[r=236,g=212,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=237,g=70,b=20], java.awt.Color[r=237,g=70,b=20], java.awt.Color[r=237,g=70,b=20], java.awt.Color[r=237,g=70,b=20], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=38,b=183], java.awt.Color[r=236,g=212,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=241,g=26,b=27], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=189,b=71], java.awt.Color[r=241,g=26,b=27], java.awt.Color[r=236,g=212,b=255]]
```

So the first 4 indexes in the array would map to `["Green","Green","Green","Green"]`

Comment: For example by your definition, R = 11, g = 199, b =11 is red, but it sure looks green to me

Comment: Its an example, it isn't practical I was just using it to explain what I was saying. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: What doesn't make sense? Using constraints to determine what each color is?  @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: so you want to determine color without using RGB values?

Comment: I want to determine the color using the RGB values but avoid doing something like `if(r > 10 && g < 200 && b < 200)`

Comment: you will have to define base colors wich you want to detect. RGB is vector, so you can try to compute distance between base color and colors in your arraylist (euclidian distance), then pick the color which has min distance i.e. is closest to given base color.

Comment: Its interesting that you mention that because I already do that to determine the RGB values that go in the array. That is why you find 4 colors in the array with the exact same RGB. I compare them to get their distance. @matoni

Comment: @cuber aren't colors in arraylist product of area colors average?

Comment: Yes but in order to get them to the same value I compared one of each different color to the rest of them and calculated their distance. If the color distance was close I would assign it to the color I was comparing it to. @matoni

Comment: @cuber if you already computed distances between average color and some base colors, you will have to define more base colors against which you will perform distance computation (to distinguish between more colors/color tones). To create base palette create colors via HUE i.e. for each angle of circle-color-model create one instance of color. After obtaining these colors derive from them another colors by lightening and darkening.

Comment: So if I was to compare my red in that image to the set `Color.RED` that wouldn't conflict with the determination of the color if I was in poor lighting and the orange  happened to look very close red? @matoni

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141799/discussion-between-matoni-and-cuber).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer cuz cannot comment.

If you think checking all r, g, b, and alpha will need too many process for processing and would take time. So you you are right. But you are wrong as this work will be as easy as ABC for a OpenCL/CUDA (or generally GPGPU) program for example.

One solution could be converting the `RGB` form to `HSL` form, and simply change the `L` to `100%` and again convert back it to `RGB`
For example, given color `[3,50,2]` in rgb form, which could be a dark green, the HSL value is `[119,96,20]`
now change the `L` value to `100%`, and convert back the value to `RGB` which is `[14,255,10]`. So now it's simply ready for your constraint check as you mentioned.

Another solution could be change the constraint value into something relative to min and max values of given color.
for example, don't assume the `g` must be over `200` to mark the color as green, instead finds the max and min of all r, g, and b values, and now check if the `g` is more than `70%` of max value.
Sample(EDIT):
Given color value as `[3,50,2]`. Now instead of assume the min value for checking a color (here the const 200), finds the max value of given color (which is 50 here) and assume the min value 70%(or anything) of max val. check the sample below.

```
int given_color=0x00033202;//3,50,2 in ARGB form in hex
int relative_max=(given_color&0xff);//not 200, default assume blue is max
int relative_min=(given_color&0xff);//not 200, default assume blue is min
int tmp;
for(int a=8;a<=16;a+=8){//check for red and green too
 tmp=(given_color>>a)&0xff;
 if(tmp<relative_min){relative_min=tmp;}
 if(tmp>relative_max){relative_max=tmp;}
}//now you have max and min of given color, here 50 and 2
//now assume the 74% of real max value is const val 200
//and the value you want to check for color
relative_max*=0.74;
relative_min*=0.74;
//now check over real amx and rel min over const values
if( (r<relative_min) && (g>relative_max) && (b>relative_max) ){}//could be cyan
//...etc
```

Comment: I like your second solution. Could you explain a little more on how I could make my markers relative? using min max of the colors?

Comment: updated with a simple sample, but I suggest the first solution which is more accurate and much easier @cuber

Comment: Ok I will use the first solution you stated. So what is would do is iterate through the color array change the RGB to HSL. Turn the brightness up? Then back to RGB and then I can use my constraints?

Comment: I really don't know what is the algorithm to change from RGB to HSL, but I know it should be implemented already in java API(not sure). For loop over pixels, it might take a notable time for large files, so go for GPGPU, it will be rocket! And you got it right, `RGB` to `HSL`, then change the `L` value to 100%(fully bright), and then change back the form from `HSL` to `RGB`, now you would check by constraints you used. Please note a black pixel could be converted to white in this form, so check data very well at all stages. @cuber

Comment: I know the algorithm, I was doing conversions before but I would use raw constraints. I do loop over 400 pixels it doesn't take long. So to just turn up the brightness and set it to 100% and bring it back to RGB.

Comment: Do you think I could use HSV instead of HSL ?

Comment: Yes, deserve a try indeed, HSV could be used too, probably changing the `V` value. @cuber

Comment: Ok I will use that instead because it turns out if I use HSL I have to do the image conversion by hand because it isn't a field in Java openCV libraries.